# GWT TabLayoutPanel - Dynamic height?

Tags: java, css, gwt, user-interface, tabpanel

I have a TabLayoutPanel and i don't want to give it a fixed height like in the following code example (`tabPanel.setHeight("100px");`). I want to give it the height of the tab content e.g. the HTML-Widget in the first tab). If i don't set the hight manually, the tab content is not shown at all. Is there any way to get this working with a height adapted to the content?

```
public class GWTTest implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(3, Unit.EM);

        tabPanel.setAnimationDuration(400);
        tabPanel.add(new HTML("Tab1 Content"), "Tab 1");

        tabPanel.add(new HTML("Tab2 Content"), "Tab 2");

        tabPanel.setHeight("100px");

        RootPanel.get().add(tabPanel);

    }
}
```

I also tried to mess around directly in the css with the "overflow" and "postition"-attributes, but this then breaks always the animation or something else.

**Edit:** It seems the easiest way would be to implement my own tab panel - or use an existing javascript library.

Answer (score 3):

Layout panels are a special kind of container in GWT that required sizes from their parents and can size themselves. The basis is the two interfaces `ProvidesResize` and `RequiresResize` - indicates that the object will size its children, the other that it must be sized when the parent's size changes. Most layout panels (like `TabLayoutPanel`) implements both - it needs a size change from its parent, and when it gets it, it will size its children, each tab.

To kick it off though, you need to add the root widget to a `RootLayoutPanel`, not a `RootPanel`. There are several chief differences - there is only one RootLayoutPanel (no `get(String)` method), and the `RootLayoutPanel` will size its children, while RootPanel will not.

Use `RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tabPanel)` instead of `RootPanel.get().add(tabPanel)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have also ran up with this issue, but sadly it requires height to be set. All the workaround s where a failure. But some of them suggest the following.

You can try to replace the `TabLayoutPanel` with a [HeaderPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HeaderPanel.html):

> A panel that includes a header (top), footer (bottom), and content
>   (middle) area. The header and footer areas resize naturally. The
>   content area is allocated all of the remaining space between the
>   header and footer area.

Alternatively you can override the `onResize()` method your `ResizeLayoutPanel` calculate the height of your embedded content and set the appropriate height.

If you want scrolling functionality you have to embed your `VerticalPanel` in a [ScrollPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) or use CSS to set the oferflow property.

Comment: So does the proposed solution work or not? :) Did you find a working solution or does it not work for you?

Comment: No proposed solution did not work for me. Tab panel requires the height to be set. May be I did some wrong.